# How to let Pythia to output the complete event record in LHEF or StDHep format?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, simulations, computational-physics, software

I am currently using [Pythia 6.4](http://pythia6.hepforge.org/) to simulate some processes (I do not have the intention to upgrade to 8). Now, I need Pythia to output its event record in the format of [LHEF](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=lhef+physics) or [StDHeP](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=stdhep+physics). I accidently found the subroutines to output LHEF format: PYUPEV, PYUPIN, PYLHEF. Unfortunately, these 3 subroutines only output parton level events. I only find quarks, gluons and leptons in the output, even if I turned on parton showering. If I turn on parton showering, PYLIST(1) gives me a long list of particles which are leptons, gauge bosons (not gluons) and hadrons, which is correct. I am not sure what happens behind the scene. Would you please help me with this?

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have much expertise on Pythia, and [most questions about it go unanswered or unhelpfully answered.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=pythia).